# Find optimal x(t) such that L(t) = R(x(t)) as close as possible.

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, image-processing

Say I am given two continuous, differentiable functions $L(t)$ and $R(t)$ defined on the interval $0 \leq t \leq 1.$ The goal is to find a function $x(t)$ $(0 \leq t \leq 1)$ that alters the domain of $R$ such that $L(t)$ and $R(x(t))$ are as close to each other as possible. For example, from the graphs in the figure below, it appears that I can horizontally stretch and translate $R$ so that it matches $L$:

[image]

More formally, I am looking for the function $x(t)$ such that the following integral is minimal:
$$
  I_{simple} = \int_o^1 \left( L(t) - R(x(t))\right)^2\ dt
$$
We will probably want $x(t)$ to be "well-behaved" (e.g., mostly monotonically non-decreasing, but not too steep or too shallow) so we can add an extra term and weighting parameter $\alpha$ that keeps the slope of $x$ close to 1:
$$
  I = \int_0^1 \left( L(t) - R(x(t))\right)^2 + \alpha\cdot(x'(t) - 1)^2\ dt
$$

According to the [Calculus of Variations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CalculusofVariations.html), the solution $x$ should obey the [Euler-Lagrange Differential Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDifferentialEquation.html). Let
$$
  F(t,x,\dot{x}) = \left(L(t) - R(x)\right)^2 + \alpha\cdot(\dot{x} - 1)^2
$$ 
then according Euler we have the following differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}} = 0.
$$
Thus in our case we have
$$
  (L(t) - R(x)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} R(x) - \alpha \cdot \ddot{x}  = 0.
$$
First of all, is that last differential equation correct ($t$ is the dependent variable)? Second of all, is this useful for finding a solution for $x$? Numerical approaches are fine too.

*Side Note: this is just a small step toward an algorithm for warping images so that they match. I am approaching the problem similar to the [Horn-Schunk Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method) for optical flow.*

Comment: For the exact case (where there is a continuous monotonic $x$ such that $L = R \circ x$) I think it is clear that the (isolated) local maxima/minima have to get mapped to eachother, so we first just have to determine the sequence of local maxima/minima. Then between each two local extrema we have a monotonic intervals (assuming $L$ and $R$ are "nice" enough). These are invertible which leads to the solution $x = R^{-1} \circ L$ on those intervals. This is only an analytical approach but probably not very useful in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You seemingly need to solve an eq. $L(t)=R(t_1)$, and find an appropriate $t_1$. If you can numerically or analytically invert your functions you will solve your problem, I  think.

Comment: R, in general, will not have a simple inverse. If it did, the solution would be trivial: x(t) = R^{-1}(L(t)) (ignoring constraints on x).

Comment: But numerically it may be (probably) possible to invert R? If it is given as an array of $t$' s and array of R' s then an inverse is immediate.

Comment: It's not that the inverse is hard to find -- the problem is that R does not have an inverse at all. Take even a simple cubic R(t) = t^3 + 3t^2 - t + 1 -- what is the inverse of R? There isn't one!

Comment: I like this approach: you can, at first, find a map between the extrema of the two functions. Between the extrema the function is a one to one map, that you can invert.

Comment: Eventually I will be working with noisy image data with false extrema -- finding corresponding points is indeed the trick (and involve about 30 years of computer vision research). I am just trying to take a fresh approach thats similar to the Horn-Shunck sol'n (see link above)  that uses Euler-Lagrance Equations.